# Adding sound to play in 2 different view controllers, and repeating the sound

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my project I have `ViewController` && `GameViewController`

When the app launches I want to play my `sound.mp3` and I want it to play in all the views and repeat the sound as long as the app runs.

I have watched almost every tutorial on Youtube without getting this to work, it's getting really frustrating.

Comment: what have you tried so far? could you post some code and explain exactly where it is not working

Comment: http://amorykcwong.ca/index.php/ict-11-12/10-info-tech/info-tech-11-12/18-ios-music-and-sound-code-snippets                 I've tried some "bites" of this code but it was to complicated...

Comment: i did´nt know what to take away and what to keep :(

Comment: and i have tried almost every tut on youtube , no code issues but ound just won't play...

Answer (score 1):

You can use AVAudioPlayer and use this code in your controllers

in your viewcontroller.h

```
    #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
    @interface CCDirectorDisplayLink : CCDirectorIOS <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
    {
     AVAudioPlayer *_backgroundMusicPlayer;
    }
```

in your viewcontroller.m

```
    -(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        [super viewDidAppear:animated];

        NSError *error;
        NSString *backgroundMusicPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourMP3" ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSURL *backgroundMusicURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:backgroundMusicPath];
        _backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
        [_backgroundMusicPlayer setDelegate:self];  // We need this so we can restart after interruptions
        [_backgroundMusicPlayer setNumberOfLoops:0];
        [_backgroundMusicPlayer play];
    }
```

Comment: doesn´t setNumberOfLoops be -1 to repeat forever? :)

Comment: You have to probably set audio session with AVAudioSession. It is singleton and then it has property active. You can set behavior of the sound like background playing or mixing option with this as well

Comment: Yes, if you setNumberOfLoops:-1 will not stop it when finish. You will need to use [_backgroundMusicPlayer stop]; but as I understood you want to play this mp3 one time, for this reason i set this property to 0. If you want a loop forever, then check it as -1

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can try playing sound in your `AppDelegate`. A quick search on google returns me following SO posts -

[IOS can I use AVAudioPlayer on the appDelegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410407/ios-can-i-use-avaudioplayer-on-the-appdelegate)

[How do you make a sound file play automatically thought an iOS app and loop using Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854997/how-do-you-make-a-sound-file-play-automatically-thought-an-ios-app-and-loop-usin)

You may try pulling out code from those and experiment. Hope this helps.